# Banco de dados + java

Tags: java, mysql

Como faço pra verificar se existe uma database, no java ?

Exemplo:

Se tiver, crie uma nova.

Answer (score 3):

Use este código abaixo:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS nomedobanco;
```

Comment: Obrigado, nem tinha pensado nisso, isso que dar programar estressado.

Comment: já aconteceu muito comigo.. Eu costumo usar a expressão: "Eu mesmo me trolei" srsrs